# Drag and Drop Program Project

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DragAndDrop extends JFrame
{
    WATCanvas canvas;

    public DragAndDrop()
    {
        super();
        Container container = getContentPane();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        canvas = new WATCanvas(800,600,45,40);
        container.add(canvas);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        container.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
          }
        });
            setSize(1200,1000);
            setVisible(true);

    }

    class WATCanvas extends JPanel
    {
        Cursor curSP, curCSF, curCDF, curUB, curPP, curMod, curKD, cur;
        int buttonLeftBorder = 900;
        int buttonTopBorder = 20;
        double spX=buttonLeftBorder, spY=buttonTopBorder+10, spW=20, spH=20;//singlePallet coordinates
        double csFX=buttonLeftBorder, csFY=buttonTopBorder+90, csFW=80, csFH=40;//caseFlow coordinates
        double cdFX=buttonLeftBorder, cdFY=buttonTopBorder+150, cdFW=40, cdFH=40;//caddyFlow coordinates
        double ubX=buttonLeftBorder, ubY=buttonTopBorder+210, ubW=80, ubH=20;//unloadBulk coordinates
        double ppX=buttonLeftBorder, ppY=buttonTopBorder+250, ppW=80, ppH=20;//prePick coordinates
        double modX=buttonLeftBorder, modY=buttonTopBorder+290, modW=40, modH=40;//module coordinates
        double kdX=buttonLeftBorder, kdY=buttonTopBorder+350, kdW=20, kdH=20;//kd coordinates
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        int width, height, rows, cols;

        Rectangle2D singlePallet;
        Rectangle2D caseFlow;
        Rectangle2D caddyFlow;
        Rectangle2D unloadBulk;
        Rectangle2D prePick;
        Rectangle2D module;
        Rectangle2D kd;
        Rectangle2D selectedShape;
        Rectangle2D boundingRec;

        public WATCanvas(int w, int h, int r, int c)
        {
            setBackground(Color.white);
            setSize(width = w, height = h);
            rows = r;
            cols = c;
            addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
            addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseMotionListener());
            setTitle("Warehouse Allocation Model");
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            Font insideDrawing = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN, 9);
            Font boldDescription = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 10);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            //single pallet location
            singlePallet = new Rectangle2D.Double(spX,spY,spW,spW);
            g2.draw(singlePallet);
            g2.setFont(insideDrawing);
            g2.drawString("xxx", buttonLeftBorder+05, buttonTopBorder+15);
            g2.setFont(boldDescription);
            g2.drawString("Single Pallet Lane", buttonLeftBorder+25, buttonTopBorder+20);

            //Multiple Pallets
            g2.setFont(insideDrawing);
            g2.drawString("xxx",buttonLeftBorder+05,buttonTopBorder+55);
            g2.drawRect(buttonLeftBorder, buttonTopBorder+50, 20, 20);
            g2.drawRect(buttonLeftBorder+20, buttonTopBorder+50, 20, 20);
            g2.drawRect(buttonLeftBorder+40, buttonTopBorder+50, 20, 20);
            g2.drawRect(buttonLeftBorder+60, buttonTopBorder+50, 20, 20);
            g2.setFont(boldDescription);
            g2.drawString("Flow Lane (4-deep example)", buttonLeftBorder+85, buttonTopBorder+60);

            //Case Flow
            caseFlow = new Rectangle2D.Double(csFX,csFY,csFW,csFH);
            g2.setFont(insideDrawing);
            g2.drawString("Case Flow", buttonLeftBorder+20, buttonTopBorder+115);
            g2.draw(caseFlow);
            g2.setFont(boldDescription);
            g2.drawString("Standard Case Flow Rack", buttonLeftBorder+85, buttonTopBorder+115);

            //Caddy Flow

            caddyFlow = new Rectangle2D.Double(cdFX,cdFY,cdFW,cdFH);
            g2.setFont(insideDrawing);
            g2.drawString("Caddy",buttonLeftBorder+10, buttonTopBorder+170);
            g2.drawString("Flow",buttonLeftBorder+12,buttonTopBorder+180);
            g2.draw(caddyFlow);
            g2.setFont(boldDescription);
            g2.drawString("Standard Caddy Flow Rack", buttonLeftBorder+45, buttonTopBorder+175);

            //Unload Bulk Door

            unloadBulk = new Rectangle2D.Double(ubX,ubY,ubW,ubH);
            g2.setFont(insideDrawing);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fill(unloadBulk);
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2.drawString("Unload/Bulk Door", buttonLeftBorder+3, buttonTopBorder+223);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setFont(boldDescription);
            g2.drawString("Unload/Bulk Door", buttonLeftBorder+85, buttonTopBorder+223);

            //Pre-Pick Trad

            prePick = new Rectangle2D.Double(ppX,ppY,ppW,ppH);
            g2.setFont(insideDrawing);
            g2.fill(prePick);
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2.drawString("PP/Trad",buttonLeftBorder+20, buttonTopBorder+263);
            g2.setFont(boldDescription);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.drawString("Pre-Pick Module", buttonLeftBorder+85, buttonTopBorder+263);

            //Module with spotted pattern

            module = new Rectangle2D.Double(modX,modY,modW,modH);
            g2.setFont(insideDrawing);
            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(5,5,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D big = bi.createGraphics();
            big.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            big.fillRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
            big.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            big.fillOval(2, 2, 2, 2);

            TexturePaint tp = new TexturePaint(bi, new Rectangle(5,5));

            g2.setPaint(tp);
            g2.fill(module);
            g2.setFont(boldDescription);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.drawString("Module", buttonLeftBorder+04, buttonTopBorder+310);
            g2.draw(module);
            g2.setFont(boldDescription);
            g2.drawString("Standard Caddy Flow Rack", buttonLeftBorder+45, buttonTopBorder+310);

            //KD with spotted pattern

            kd = new Rectangle2D.Double(kdX,kdY,kdW,kdH);
            BufferedImage bi2 = new BufferedImage(5,5,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D big2 = bi2.createGraphics();
            big2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            big2.fillRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
            big2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            big2.fillOval(2, 2, 2, 2);

            TexturePaint tp2 = new TexturePaint(bi2, new Rectangle(5,5));

            g2.setPaint(tp2);
            g2.fill(kd);
            g2.setFont(boldDescription);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.drawString("KD", buttonLeftBorder+4, buttonTopBorder+365);
            g2.draw(kd);
            g.setFont(boldDescription);
            g.drawString("KD Stands", buttonLeftBorder+25, buttonTopBorder+365);

            width = 900;
            height = 800;
            int start = 25;

            int rowHt = 20;
            for(int j=0;j<=rows;++j)
                g.drawLine(start, start + j*rowHt, height+start,start + j*rowHt);

            int rowWid = 20;
            for(int k=0;k<=cols;++k)
                g.drawLine(start+k*rowWid, start, start + k*rowWid, width+start);

            if (cur != null)
                setCursor(cur);
        }

        class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (singlePallet.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = singlePallet;
                    if (boundingRec != null)
                        boundingRec = singlePallet.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (caseFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = caseFlow;
                    if (boundingRec != null)
                        boundingRec = caseFlow.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (caddyFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = caddyFlow;
                    if (boundingRec != null)
                        boundingRec = caddyFlow.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (unloadBulk.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = unloadBulk;
                    if (boundingRec != null)
                        boundingRec = unloadBulk.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (prePick.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = prePick;
                    if (boundingRec != null)
                        boundingRec = prePick.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (module.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = module;
                    if (boundingRec != null)
                        boundingRec = module.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (kd.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = kd;
                    if (boundingRec != null)
                        boundingRec = kd.getBounds2D();
                }
                else
                {
                    boundingRec = null;
                }

                canvas.repaint();
                x1 = e.getX();
                y1 = e.getY();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (singlePallet.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = singlePallet.getBounds2D();
                    selectedShape = singlePallet;
                }
                else if (caseFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = caseFlow.getBounds2D();
                    selectedShape = caseFlow;
                }
                else if (caddyFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = caddyFlow.getBounds2D();
                    selectedShape = caddyFlow;
                }
                else if (unloadBulk.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = unloadBulk.getBounds2D();
                    selectedShape = unloadBulk;
                }
                else if (prePick.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = prePick.getBounds2D();
                    selectedShape = prePick;
                }
                else if (module.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = module.getBounds2D();
                    selectedShape = module;
                }
                else if (kd.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = kd.getBounds2D();
                    selectedShape = kd;
                }

                //canvas.repaint();
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (singlePallet.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = singlePallet;
                    boundingRec = singlePallet.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (caseFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = caseFlow;
                    boundingRec = caseFlow.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (caddyFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = caddyFlow;
                    boundingRec = caddyFlow.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (unloadBulk.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = unloadBulk;
                    boundingRec = unloadBulk.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (prePick.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = prePick;
                    boundingRec = prePick.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (module.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = module;
                    boundingRec = module.getBounds2D();
                }
                else if (kd.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    selectedShape = kd;
                    boundingRec = kd.getBounds2D();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (boundingRec != null)
                        boundingRec = null;
                }
                canvas.repaint();
            }
        }

        class MyMouseMotionListener extends MouseMotionAdapter
        {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (singlePallet.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = null;
                    selectedShape = singlePallet;
                    x2 = e.getX();
                    y2 = e.getY();
                    spX = spX + x2 - x1;
                    spY = spY + y2 - y1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    y1 = y2;       
                     canvas.repaint();
                }
                else if (caseFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = null;
                    selectedShape = caseFlow;
                    x2 = e.getX();
                    y2 = e.getY();
                    csFX = csFX + x2 - x1;
                    csFY = csFY + y2 - y1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    y1 = y2;
                     canvas.repaint();

                }
                else if (caddyFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = null;
                    selectedShape = caseFlow;
                    x2 = e.getX();
                    y2 = e.getY();
                    cdFX = cdFX + x2 - x1;
                    cdFY = cdFY + y2 - y1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    y1 = y2;
                     canvas.repaint();

                }
                else if (unloadBulk.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = null;
                    selectedShape = caseFlow;
                    x2 = e.getX();
                    y2 = e.getY();
                    ubX = ubX + x2 - x1;
                    ubY = ubY + y2 - y1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    y1 = y2;
                      canvas.repaint();
                }
                else if (prePick.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = null;
                    selectedShape = caseFlow;
                    x2 = e.getX();
                    y2 = e.getY();
                    ppX = ppX + x2 - x1;
                    ppY = ppY + y2 - y1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    y1 = y2;
                     canvas.repaint();

                }
                else if (module.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = null;
                    selectedShape = caseFlow;
                    x2 = e.getX();
                    y2 = e.getY();
                    modX = modX + x2 - x1;
                    modY = modY + y2 - y1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    y1 = y2;
                     canvas.repaint();

                }
                else if (kd.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                {
                    boundingRec = null;
                    selectedShape = caseFlow;
                    x2 = e.getX();
                    y2 = e.getY();
                    kdX = kdX + x2 - x1;
                    kdY = kdY + y2 - y1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    y1 = y2;
                      canvas.repaint();
                }

      }

            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if(singlePallet != null && caseFlow != null && caddyFlow != null && unloadBulk != null
                        && prePick != null && module != null && kd != null)
                {
                    if (singlePallet.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    {
                        cur = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                    }

                    else if (caseFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    {
                        cur = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                    }

                    else if (caddyFlow.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    {
                        cur = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                    }

                    else if (unloadBulk.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    {
                        cur = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                    }

                    else if (prePick.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    {
                        cur = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                    }

                    else if (module.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    {
                        cur = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                    }

                    else if (kd.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    {
                        cur = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        cur = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();                   
                    }
            }
                canvas.repaint();
            }
        }

}
        public static void main(String arg[])
        {
            new DragAndDrop();
        }

}
```

The problem is that the dragged item is leaving a track like in the image.
all i want to do is drag the items to the grid then get its coordinates in the grid lines
can you help me to stop its leaving its tracks while being drag

any kind of help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()` NOT paint().
2. Don't forget to invoke `super.paintComponent()` at the start of the method to clear the background before the painting is redone.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is right here...

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Font insideDrawing = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN, 9);
    Font boldDescription = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 10);

     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

     //single pallet location
     singlePallet = new Rectangle2D.Double(spX,spY,spW,spW);
```

You failed to call `super.paint(g)` which would prepare the `Graphics` context for painting....This should be done (most often) BEFORE you start doing you own painting

You shouldn't be using `paint`, but should be using `paintComponent`

Which I highlighted in [this (very simular) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938493/drag-and-drop-dragging-problems/19941524#19941524)

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details